# Compare a list against multiple vectors, break 'loop', and populate new column

Tags: r, list, break

Am new to R and have search for answers. Learned a lot in the last 2 weeks from finding answers I could modify.  This time I'm really stuck.

I wish to populate a new variable, Abuse, depending on the values across 20+ columns.  The values I look for are prioritized, such that I wish

- to 'break' the search if a value is found,
- populate Abuse with a string,
- and restart the search with the next 'row'.

As a SAS programmer I've coded this with a do while loop - and am trying very hard to learn the advantage of vectors in R.

There are 20+ diag_codes and have included only a few here.

```
   diag_codes <- c("admitting_diagnosis", "princ_diag_code",   
"oth_diag_code_1",
"oth_diag_code_2" )


non_fall2_flag  <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
                "admitting_diagnosis princ_diag_code poa_princ_diag_code oth_diag_code_1 poa_oth_diag_code_1 oth_diag_code_2

                          27651   73026   Y   99559   Y   80703
                          99550   99550   Y   85220   Y   591
                          78609   486 Y   99559   Y   1320
                          78039   78609   Y   7707    Y   99550
                          78065   99559   Y   9916    Y   3379
                          99550   99554   Y   3158    Y   1330
                          9941    9941    Y   99559   Y   2760
                          78039   99559   Y   51889   Y   V1505
                          ")
```

Thanks to @42- @42 this solution works:

```
      non_fall2_flag$abuse <-  apply( non_fall2_flag[diag_codes], 1, 
   function(x) if('99559' %in% x) {"other abuse"} else 
  if ('99550' %in% x) {"unspec."} else {""} )
```

That prompted me to try a similar task that needed more flexibility - but the commented line does not work.  The substring comparison to multiple values will not work.

```
diag_codes <- c("admitting_diagnosis", "princ_diag_code",   
            "oth_diag_code_1",
            "oth_diag_code_2" )




child_data <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
                       "admitting_diagnosis princ_diag_code poa_princ_diag_code oth_diag_code_1 poa_oth_diag_code_1 oth_diag_code_2

                          27651   73026   Y   99559   Y   80103
                          99550   99550   Y   85220   Y   591
                          78609   486 Y   99559   Y   1320
                          78039   92519   Y   7707    Y   99550
                          78065   99559   Y   9916    Y   3379
                          99550   99554   Y   3158    Y   1330
                          9941    9941    Y   95901   Y   2760
                          78039   99559   Y   80389   Y   V1505
                          ")

child_data$broad <-  apply( child_data[,diag_codes] ,1 ,
                           function(x) 
                             # if (substr(x,1,3)  %in% c('800', '801', '803')) {1} else 
                              if ( any( '9251' == substr(x,1,4) )  ) {1} else 
                       if ( any( '95901'  == substr(x,1,5))  ) {1} else {0})
```

Comment: But we do not have an unambiguous description of the structure or code to create `child_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a few things to unlearn from your SAS days, but first here's a solution:

```
 non_fall2_flag$abuse <-  apply( non_fall2_flag[diag_codes], 1, 
       function(x) if('99559' %in% x) {"other abuse"} else 
                        if ('99550' %in% x) {"unspec."} else {""} )
```

The things to unlearn are that R does not have an implicit row-oriented looping mechanism in the manner of what you are familiar with in data steps. The second is that `ifelse` is designed to return vectors but you should not be using `<-` inside the consequent and alternate expressions. Instead you need to provide two vectors and the ifelse machinery will do the choosing. Any assignment should be outside the `ifelse`. If you had been working with a single column rather than wanting to test multiple columns at once, you could have used `ifelse`.

My code used %in% to apply the membership test across an entire row at a time. When `apply` is used with a second argument of `1`, an entire row is passed to the formal argument of the function in the third position. Another approach to processing several columns at one might have been to use `mapply`, but then you would have needed to separately extract the columns and that would ahve been a lot more bulky code.

I modified your data sample so that at least two of hte lines would match your test and this then succeeded:

```
non_fall2_flag $broad <-  apply( non_fall2_flag[,diag_codes] ,1 ,
                            function(x) 
                              if ( any( '9251' == substr(x,1,4) )  ) {1} else 
                           if ( any( '95901'  == substr(x,1,5))  ) {1} else {0})
non_fall2_flag
```

Note that the `any` function will collapse a set of logical tests down to a single value, whereas your code would have only tested the first value of the vector returned by `substr`.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  I had used the %in% to select all records with '99559' or '99550' - and may now try to combine that step with your code. Or just be happy it works - regardless of the amt of code (right now).  Can the argument of '1' in: non_fall2_flag[diag_codes], 1,  also be denoted with a comma within [diag_codes]?  Sometimes I see commas in the brackets.  Much to learn.

Comment: No. The `1` as the second argument in apply is not going to succeed inside brackets. You could have used either `non_fall2_flag[diag_codes]` or `non_fall2_flag[ , diag_codes]`. When there are more than one argument to `"["`, the second argument denotes columns assuming it is being used with a  dataframe. The `non_fall2_flag[diag_codes]` is using straight list character indexing.

Comment: Yes - I wasn't clear and meant if the '1' can be instead indicated with the [, diag_codes].  I will try to better understand the difference with the comma and without -

Comment: I don't see that as succeeding. `if(.){} else{}` would aqccept only the first item fromthe vector returned by `substr`. You still haven't  appeared to understand that you CANNOT use `<-` in either the second or third positions of `ifelse`. There are many SO questions and answers about when to use ifelse versus `if(){}else{}`. Generally R-noobs, especially those coming from SPSS or SAS, will fail with `if` because they think it gets applied row wise.

Comment: The reason I was able to get away with using `if` is that the `%in%` function returns only a single value when its first argument is of length 1. Your construction is not satisfying that requirement because you reversed the relative positions.

Comment: I assumed that if you understood that was a likely source of error that you would have corrected the places where it is still present in your question. The proper way to respond to comments is by editing the question body rather than making further comments.

Comment: Oh - didn't know questions should/could be edited.  Apologize for your frustration.  Have tried to do so and deleted my improper comments.

Comment: Not easy to get one's head around!  The `%in%` function did not need `any` to test a value against a vector (your 1st suggested code) - but using `==` did require `any`.  it doesn't feel like the `substr` function is the reason for the difference - are `%in%` vs (`any` and `==`) equivalent?  And any hints to tackle the incorrectly coded line would be grand - `# if (substr(x,1,3)  %in% c('800', '801', '803')) {1} else`

Comment: In the first instance there was only a length-1 vector in the first argument to `%in%` son only a length-1 vector would be returned. In the second instance you were testing a vector of length greater than one, but you wanted a single result. Hence, the need for the additional call to `any()` to collapse the results to a single value. You say you have "incorrect" code, but you should also say what result is desired. (I thought I had answered the question.)

Comment: As I mentioned - the commented line is where I'm stuck.  All of your suggested code has, indeed, worked very well.  It's this final complexity I can't get to work `# if (substr(x,1,3) %in% c('800', '801', '803')) {1} else`  And I did play around with `any` for this line to no avail.

Comment: If you just use `max( substr(x,1,3)  %in% c('800', '801', '803'))` you get what appears to be correct answers. That would convert the multiple logical values to either 0 or 1 and this gets handled a "logical" values by `if` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the logic of your question / code correctly:

if '99559' is present, then abuse<-"other abuse"
elseif '99550' is present, then abuse<-"other abuse"
else abuse<-""

Here is some neat vectorized code to solve this.

```
# put the codes into a matrix for faster processing
myMat <- sapply(non_fall2_flag[, diag_codes],
                function(i) as.integer(gsub("[^0-9]+", "", i)))
# get indicators for both codes
check_1 <- as.integer(rowSums(myMat == 99559) > 0)
check_2 <- as.integer(rowSums(myMat == 99550) > 0)

# fill in variable
non_fall2_flag$abuse <-
                   c("", "other abuse", "unspec.")[pmax(1, 2*check_2, 3*check_1)]
```

The last line uses the two check vectors to fill in the different strings and `pmax(1, 2*check_2, 3*check_1)` is set up according to the logic above.

This returns

```
non_fall2_flag
  admitting_diagnosis princ_diag_code poa_princ_diag_code oth_diag_code_1 poa_oth_diag_code_1 oth_diag_code_2       abuse
1               27651           73026                   Y           99559                   Y           80703     unspec.
2               99550           99550                   Y           85220                   Y             591 other abuse
3               78609             486                   Y           99559                   Y            1320     unspec.
4               78039           78609                   Y            7707                   Y           99550 other abuse
5               78065           99559                   Y            9916                   Y            3379     unspec.
6               99550           99554                   Y            3158                   Y            1330 other abuse
7                9941            9941                   Y           99559                   Y            2760     unspec.
8               78039           99559                   Y           51889                   Y           V1505     unspec.
```

Comment: Hi.  Thank you for the idea - new to data.matrix.  However, when I tried it, the values for admitting diagnosis, for instance, changed.  In myMat I see:admitting_diagnosis
1237
7333
5521
5421
5437
7333
7318
5421 ??  And the 4th row in your results below should be tagged "unspec." with the 99550 code... so I'm a bit unclear on the logic.

Comment: Ah. The final variable (oth_diag_code_2) is a factor rather than a numeric because of the V1505. I'll add a "fix" removes non-numeric characters prior to creating the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  It's still not working for me - and as I understand the first suggestion I'll stick with that.  Check_1 and Check_2 are entirely NAs.  Best.